# Weird behaviour/rendering of backspace in Terminal.app when SSHing into zsh using tmux/screen

Tags: ssh, terminal, terminal.app, zsh

I just stumbled upon a weird problem. When I SSH into my server (centos, zsh) and I type some stuff and hit backspace It *looks* like a space - but internally it really deleted the characters.

```
ls -l a
```

Note that the space between `l`and `a` is actually when I hit backspace. When I now hit return `ls -a` gets executed. This is only in zsh, in bash it works fine.

Hope anyone has an idea what this is all about and how to fix this.

### Update: Only happens when using tmux/screen

I also cannot clear the screen:

```
helium:~% echo $TERM
screen-256color
helium:~% clear
'screen-256color': unknown terminal type.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's unusual.  I'd start by seeing whether Ctrl-L works (ie, zsh knows your terminal and can issue a clear-screen) and running `echo $TERM` to see what terminal type zsh received from Terminal.app; I have Terminal.app send `xterm-color` and that seems to be portable and accepted.

Another thing to check is what happens when you type Ctrl-H, but I thought that all modern systems had settled on 0x7F for backspace.

*[post-update with screen information:]*

Bash has more built-in hacks for assuming that missing terminal types are ANSI-ish, but your root problem is that the `$TERM` is unrecognised. This will break most apps that want to issue control directives to the terminal emulator.  Override `$TERM` in your `~/.zprofile`:

```
case ${TERM} in
  screen-256color) TERM=screen.xterm-xfree86
  ;;
esac
```

This is part of the problem of termcap/terminfo -- it relies upon everyone having the same names, everyone being updated, etc.  No negotiation is done.

Comment: Updated my post. This behaviour is only when using tmux/screen. In tmux Ctrl-L does not work properly and Ctrl-H doesn't do a thing. Added some more infos to my intro post.

Comment: Updated my answer, Nils' comment above applies to the first 2 paragraphs of my text.

Comment: in which .zprofile? On my local machine or on the server? :)

Comment: On the server since that's the Linux box with that particular terminfo entry; or in your `~/.zshrc` of the local machine you could just override $TERM to something more portable.  Or use the `term` directive inside `~/.screenrc`.

Comment: (ahem: the server is the Linux box *missing* that particular terminfo entry; sorry for any confusion)

Comment: Note: `xterm-color` represents an older branch of xterm and is no longer recommended for use with Terminal, which these days is more compatible with current xterm. The following are preferred: `xterm-256color`, `xterm-16color`, `xterm`.